# Is there a way to detect all the autocommand that have been triggered?

Tags: autocmd, filetype, debugging

I have a file for which the `filetype` is not correctly set.

The `filetype` is set by an `autocmd` but I would like to identify which one.

How can I know which `autocmd` have been triggered when I load my buffer and where these `autocmd` have been defined?

Or alternatively can I see the list of all `autocmd` that are currently defined:

- Their orders (priority)
- Their definition (script, line number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
:verbose autocmd
```

Or with the [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin:

```
:Verbose autocmd
```

I can then search the result for my file pattern (e.g. `*.cfg`) or the filetype it has been assigned too (e.g. `cfg`)

I can then filter the output with the following two commands:

```
:g!/\v(^\s+\*\.cfg\_.{-}Last set.*$|^\S.*$)/d
:g/^\S.*\n^\S/d
```

To get only the lines that are relevant for the `*.cfg` file pattern.

Comment: Also `:filter`, but not all commands are supported IIUC

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble. Could you develop a bit about `:filter`? Do you propose that I use filter to focus the result of `verbose autocmd` to focus on the lines that are relevant to the question. How do you propose to use `:filter`

Comment: One would hope that `:filter /pat/ autocmd` would work, but alas it does not